# Return unique values from a sequence

Tags: python

I want to return a list of items from a sequence without any elements with the same value next to each other and preserving the original item order.

**I've written a solution that works** but my attempt to make this solution more pythonic does not work. It seems the `if` statement isn't working; it just returns the whole original sequence in a list.

The solution should be a function and I don't want to use imports.

```
Def order(iterable):
    iter_list = list(iterable)
    item_list = []
    item_list.append(iter_list[item] for item in range(0, len(iter_list)) if iter_list[item] != iter_list[item -1])
    return iter_list
```

**I just need to know why (if iter_list[item] != iter_list[item -1) is not working**

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE]?

Comment: `append` makes no sense here. You add one item to your list and that is a generator that would create the data if you iterate over it (e.g. `print(list(item_list[0]))`). If you want a list comprehension it would be `item_list = [iter_list[item] for item in range(0, len(iter_list)) if iter_list[item] != iter_list[item - 1]]` and you will have to return `item_list` of course.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias just what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code works just fine if you just take what's inside `append` if we somehow account for the first element. One way is:

```
out = [iter_list[item] for item in range(0, len(iter_list)) if (item==0 or iter_list[item] != iter_list[item -1])]
```

Comment: Preservation of original order is prerequisite in the question.

Comment: Your `set` solution breaks for `[1,2,1]`.

Comment: `[i for i,j in zip(lst,lst[1:]) if i!=j]` will not work if the last item isn't a duplicate from the item before.

Comment: After your 5th edit: this fails for `[1, 2, 1]`, it returns `[2, 1]`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I realized that. I think it works for `[1,2,1]` now. Wow what a mess. Sorry about that.

Comment: A solution like the current one is like saying: "OK, there's a big hole in the floor, but we put a carpet over it so everything looks fine". Yes, the result looks OK, but the real fix would be to close the hole which in this case means: change the algorithm. (This comment might not be valid any more at the time you read it since the answer keeps changing).

Comment: @Matthias Do you mean the hole that swallows the `None` from input `[None]` when using *your* solution? :-P

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes I need to work on this, I think the 1st element of every sequence should be returned. thanks

Comment: @KellyBundy I had a feeling someone would come up with this but I didn't want to overcomplicate things. Throw in a `fillvalue=object()` as the last parameter to `zip_longest` and you're fine.

Comment: @Matthias Still swallows [the Borg](https://tio.run/##TY2xbsMwEEN3fQW7SYCXIksQwEu/oVtgCEpySlUoOuV0Duz@vBshSzhwIMHHuuoPl92@yrZF4RuSkihzbki3yqL4S9VnLldqasw5h9bwxXI9GDx1oQjv6e69bZTjgFBWLuRebZeQzlLwLTMZcwkaMOLYAdZNRqjNWXuyILJgGbAilfdP2zcDuh8/D9OAmHJ@hDzTyKdfOqt1DiliwceIdTJVUlH7Artt@wc).

Answer (score 0):

If you `zip` the list with the same list starting at index 1 you're quite close to your goal but you might miss the last element.

```
data = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
result = [x for x, y in zip(data, data[1:]) if x != y]
print(result)
```

This gives you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, but we would expect an additional `8` in the list.

To get the last value too we can use `itertools.zip_longest`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
result = [x for x, y in zip_longest(data, data[1:]) if x != y]
print(result)
```

This results in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

If you don't want to duplicate the list then use `islice`.

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

data = [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]
result = [x for x, y in zip_longest(data, islice(data, 1, None)) if x != y]
print(result)
```

Comment: Here's another *trick* newlist = [a for a, b in zip(alist, alist[1:]+[None]) if a != b]

Comment: @JCaesar I try to avoid that, but it works. My favorite is the solution with `zip_longest` and `islice`.

Comment: Your first solution returns `[1, 2]` for `data = [1, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's why I said "... close to your goal". I'll emphasize that.

Comment: I'd say if you're gonna use itertools, use groupby.